# cannot communicate to localserver from minikube pod

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a local server I'm running that I'm trying to send requests to from a pod running in a single node local minikube cluster, but I'm getting connection refused. I can curl the service locally and it works find. What can I do to allow outbound connections to hit my localserver? I do `minikube ssh` and I can curl google.com or example.com fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found from their posts on Github that
`host.minikube.internal` is a new variable usable to access the host machine. Curling this using `ssh minikube` proves access.